# Sql Server - Database Backup Time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, backup

I've been doing a lot of database backups and restores of late, and I've been wondering how if the backup takes 10-15 minutes to capture, how it can still show a snapshot of the database at a split second in time?

How does Sql Server accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

You are asking how Database Snapshots work - there is a good article on this on MS [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187054%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

The short answer: it is so fast because when you do a snapshot you do not backup or copy any data. All that is done - is an empty file created.

Comment: Also read on performance implications of using snapshots for SQL Server, so that you don't get nasty surprises as you use them: http://download.microsoft.com/download/d/9/4/d948f981-926e-40fa-a026-5bfcf076d9b9/dbsnapshotperf.docx